# What's the best way to share data between components in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a Flex application that I'm working on for a new job.  It's sort of a training wheels application -- I'm learning the language, and this isn't an app that needs to talk to a service in order to do its job.  There are a few instances of combo boxes throughout the application that share the same set of possible values (say, a selection of states:  "In Progress", "Rejected", "Complete") that I want to have use the same data source.

What is the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC architecture ....well in simple cases just the Model part:

```
package 
{


    [Bindable]
    public final class ShellModelSingleton
    {   


        public var selectedStatus:ArrayCollection;




        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        // ****DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE*******
        /////////////////////////////////////////// 
        public function ShellModelSingleton(){}

        /****************************************************************
         * Singleton logic - this makes sure only 1 instance is created
         * Note: you are able to hack this since the constructor doesn't limit 
             * a single instance
         * so make sure the getInstance function is used instead of new 
             * ShellModelSingleton()
         *****************************************************************/ 
        public static function getInstance():ShellModelSingleton {
            if(_instance == null) {
                _instance = new ShellModelSingleton();
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        protected static var _instance:ShellModelSingleton;
    }

}
```

Then you can update and use the singleton from any component like this:

```
[Bindable] private var model:ShellModelSingleton = 
                              ShellModelSingleton.getInstance();
```

Component 1

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myDG" dataProvider="{model.selectedStatus}" />
```

Component 2

```
   <mx:List id="myList" dataProvider="{model.selectedStatus}" 
      labelField="label" />
```

Then any changes you make to the selectedStatus collection will be updated in both components.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize them to an array in our parent component.

Comment: Suppose that they don't all share a common parent component?

Comment: I meant parent component as in your application component. Variables declared in there essentially have global scope.