# Multiple active screens in pure MVC how to manage notification for particular screen?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, puremvc

PURE MVC -

In my application there are multiple screens which are minimized like in windows desktop.
Now each has different instances of mediator which have same notification.
So if I do changes in one screen say press some button >> which sends some command  >> to proxy >>then proxy sends notifications to mediator.

But as multiple screens are active there it is showing changes in all screens as they are notified too by proxies .

How to make sure that proxy calls to particular view component (mediator ) and not for all live instances of mediators ?

Answer (score 0):

In the PureMVC structure the Proxy notifications are send to all instances of the mediators 
though you can restrict the action performed to all other components apart from the selected one.like below

- assign the selected component to [singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312318/singleton-class-in-flex) variable during button click
- check the id in handleNotification function in mediator like below

**Example:**

```
    public static const ADD_BOLD_STYLE:String = "AddBoldStyle";

    public function TextElementMediator(objViewComponent:Object)
    {
        super(NAME, objViewComponent);
        _objTextData = objTextData; 
    }

    public function get textElement():TextElement
    {
        return viewComponent as TextElement;
    }

    override public function listNotificationInterests():Array
    {
        return [ADD_BOLD_STYLE];
    }

    override public function handleNotification(notification:INotification):void
    {
        switch(notification.getName())
        {               
            case ADD_BOLD_STYLE:
                if(textelement == singleton.selectedObject)
                {
                    //Process your data
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

here singleton refers to selectedObject

Comment: this solution might fail in case of cascade windows open .How to handle if window A opens B and B opens C ??

Answer (score 0):

The way you have phrased the question is that you are pressing a button in one of the screens and want to update *that* view. What should happen is that the view should dispatch an event to the mediator. Only if you need business logic or data from the proxy should you send a notification to the command tier. You say that you are notifying the proxy which leads me to believe that you need FRESH data from the proxy i.e. you are requesting *new* data from the backend. When the new data is retrieved it would send a notification to the mediator to update the view with the fresh data. The rest of the application should update if the data has changed.

If not all mediators care about this data then you should probably subclass the mediator for your different windows and override the 'execute' method.