# Example Flex Zend AMF Sharing Web Services Between Components in ViewStack

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I've been searching for the last couple days but can't seem to find a basic example of what I'm looking for.  I'm developing a Flex 4.5 app and in it I have a viewstack of 2 components that use some of the same services.  Currently the only way I can get the app to correctly use the web services is by defining 2 different web services that use the same PHP web service file.

For example: I have an app, and within it I have a viewstack with tab navigation of 2 components:  #1) retrieve a list of all Salary Employees, and #2) retrieve a list of all Contractors.  Currently to get it working I am defining a UsersTableEmployees webservice within component #1 and a UsersTableContractors webservice within component #2, but they both point to the same PHP class, and only differ in the arugment value I pass to them. Ie, getUsers("employee") and getUsers("contractors"). Of course this is not best practice.

Searching StackOverflow and Google gives me many results about ColdFusion and MVC (example [What's the best way to share data between components in Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104701/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-components-in-flex)), but I'm still confused. Can anyone here point me to a basic example (even sample MVC) and source code of an app that uses Zend AMF and allows different components to call common web services?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some basic encapsulation.

Wrap up the service code into a single class; and pass an instance of that class into your view component.  Or you could create a single instance of the services class and pass it into each view component as a property.

If you wanted, you can get much more complicated with it, though.  Many Frameworks, such as Robotlegs or Swiz, try to help solve this problem.